# Problem with Drupal 6 built in "normal" caching - users getting data several days old on front page

Tags: caching, performance

I have a site running Drupal 6. I was having performance problems so I turned on Drupal's built in "normal" level of caching performance -- which claims to not have any side effects.

Since I enabled this feature (about 3 days ago) I have users reporting that they are not seeing the latest content -- specifically the latest posts on the front page appear to be from several days ago. I believe this is happening both for logged in users, and anonymous users. I have not yet seen it happen as either a logged in user or an anonymous user.

What might be causing this and what steps can I take to troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to look at:

1. Adjust the Minimum cache lifetime set at on admin/settings/performance to something better suited to your users.
2. Make sure you have cron tasks in place to rebuild that cache on a regular interval. You can do it using [Poormanscron](http://drupal.org/project/poormanscron) in D6 (Built in core in D7).
3. Disable any server-side performace/caching mechanisms, such as APC, memcache, varnish etc...
4. Disable any extra Drupal caching mechanism, such as Boost.

Comment: Minimum cache lifetime was set to <none>. I checked the log to verify that cron is running and it is running every 15 minutes. Anything else that I can look at that might be causing this?

Comment: added a couple more

Comment: I had tried out Boost previously and forgot that boost had me add a bunch of stuff to .htaccess. I removed all that stuff now so I'll see if that fixes it.

Comment: I would almost guarantee that is your culprit, then. What's going to happen now though is that the users that visited your site while boost was installed will still see a cached version. It's because their browsers are told to hold onto that cache. They will have to refresh their browser cache or wait for the boost cache lifetime to expire.